# Domain and IP should have different DocumentRoot

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, localhost, configuration

the Domain points to an IP / Server. But I like to have different documentRoots if the server is accessed via IP or via Domain. Therefore I build this configuration:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAdmin foo@bar

  DocumentRoot /var/www/localhost
  <Directory /var/www/localhost>
    Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
  </Directory> 
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAdmin foo@bar
  ServerName example.org
  ServerAlias example.org

  DocumentRoot /var/www/example.org
  <Directory /var/www/example.org>
    Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
  </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

The problem is that accessing the IP or the domain will lead to the same page. What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your config has one virtualhost with a servername of example.com, however **the other virtualhost has no servername directive**.

Lets say your ip is 10.0.0.1

You need to supply the servername of 10.0.0.1 for the virtualhost you want to respond to that ip.

Something like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAdmin foo@bar

  ServerName 10.0.0.1

  DocumentRoot /var/www/localhost
  <Directory /var/www/localhost>
    Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
  </Directory> 
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: That was obvious but I didn't saw it. Thanks so much! Works like a charm.